# Request a Blockchain API V2 to receive Payments

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, but I have a problem with the Blockchain API V2, I tried too many times to request it, but never getting an answer nor my API!? I don't know why.
I searched the web looking for people whom having the same problem as I am, but find nothing. Also I didn't find a way to contact them asking about the delay in giving a simple API code!.
So if anyone has a better idea please let me know.
As an addition I am going to use it in a thirdparty software, where I am not able to add other Bitcoin payments instead of Blockchain one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why exactly, but they have become extremely strict as to who they give API keys now. Previously it was very easy, and now they heavily investigate the intended usage. I wouldn't be surprised if the reason has to do with gambling sites and scams that were using their API.

As for recommendations you can run your own node on a VPS or use another 3rd party API. The only one that is as easy to use as blockchain.info, but actually gives out API keys is block.io. The catch is the free version is severely limited. There's also blocktrail, and blockcypher.